# Get current/statechanged cell signal strength. onStateSignalChanged never invoked

Tags: java, android

**GOAL:** get current/statechanged cell signal strength.

**PROBLEM:** reading around (here and on developer.android web site) brought me to this code. But it doesn't work. I mean I've tried to set a breakpoint on `onSignalStrengthChanged` callback invocation but is never called. 
I've also declared coarse location permission on android manifest (is needed for `getAllCellInfo()`.

**QUESTIONS:**

1) why  `onSignalStrengthChanged` is never called ?

2) I imagine that the aforementioned callback will be invoked just when the signal strength will change. But how can I get the current signal strength before it changes?

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            telephonyManager.listen(new PhoneStateListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
}

public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength){
            try{
                int level;

                for (final CellInfo info : telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo() ){

                    if (info instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
                        final CellSignalStrengthGsm gsm = ((CellInfoGsm) info).getCellSignalStrength();
                        // do what you need
                        level = gsm.getLevel();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "gsm rssi"+level, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (info instanceof CellInfoCdma) {
                        final CellSignalStrengthCdma cdma = ((CellInfoCdma) info).getCellSignalStrength();
                        // do what you need
                        level = cdma.getLevel();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cdma rssi"+level, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (info instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                        final CellSignalStrengthLte lte = ((CellInfoLte) info).getCellSignalStrength();
                        // do what you need
                        level = lte.getLevel();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lte rssi"+level, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        throw new Exception("Unknown type of cell signal!");
                    }


                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }
```

Comment: You don't pass in a new PhoneStateListener.  You pass in a subclass that implements onSignalStrengthChanged.  Its a callback interface.  Just defining that function in your own class does nothing (unless you pass in this and have your class implement PhoneStateListener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Define below mentioned variables globally :

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
MyPhoneStateListener psListener;
TextView txtSignalStr;
```

`onCreate` Method :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 psListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
 telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 telephonyManager.listen(psListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
}
```

Create an inner class that will extend `PhoneStateListener`

and use `@Override` annotation before `onSignalStrengthsChanged` method like

Create `MyPhoneStateListener` Class :

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
@Override
public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
{
 super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
//your Code
 }
}
```

Comment: sorry for the noob qeustion...so can I use inner class inside my mainActivity class?

Comment: Yes you can use inner class inside your mainActivity class.

Comment: I've just tried but still the callback is never invoked. I thought because of I was debugging in a fixed position using a usb cable so I tried to move around checking for Toast I've inserted in the callback but nothing appeared.

Comment: Please tell your phone Android version

Comment: If your android version is greater than or equal 6 than add dynamic permission. Moreover this code is running on my phone nicely.

Comment: Android API version is 17. 
Anyway now it starts to execute the callback method but getAllCellInfo() return null.
A question: if in oncreate method I already grant coarse location permission have I to check it again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177908/discussion-between-maicake-and-anisuzzaman-babla).